# How to get selected timezone from dropdown in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, timezone

Drop down for timezones in form

```
<%= time_zone_select :time_zone, ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all, nil,
 {:include_blank => false,:prompt=>"Select Time Zone"} %>
```

After selecting some timezone and submitting form, when I do params["time_zone"] I get

```
"#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00000001ff5450 @name=%22American Samoa%22, @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Pacific/Pago_Pago>, 
 @current_period=#<TZInfo::TimezonePeriod: #<TZInfo::TimezoneTransitionDefinition: #<TZInfo::TimeOrDateTime: 439038000>,#<TZInfo::TimezoneOffset: -39600,0,SST>>,nil>>, 
#<ActiveSupport::TimeZone:0x00000002024bb0 @name=%22International Date Line West%22, @utc_offset=nil, @tzinfo=#<TZInfo::TimezoneProxy: Pacific/Midway>,..............
```

How I get selected timezone? **Note:** I save timezone in string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply call `.name` on the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` object:

```
irb(main):055:0> ActiveSupport::TimeZone.new("American Samoa").name
=> "American Samoa"
```

You can can do this with a custom setter. Example:

```
class City < ActiveRecord::Base
  # automatically convert ActiveSupport::TimeZone 
  # objects into a serializable string.
  def time_zone=(tz) 
    super(tz.try(:name) || tz)
  end
end

class CitiesController
  def create
    @city = City.create(city_params)
    respond_with(@city)
  end

  def city_params
    params.require(:city).permit(:time_zone)
  end
end
```

Comment: PLease ellaborate this.I can't understand this

Comment: You can get the name of the timezone by `params[:time_zone].name`. By creating a custom setter on your model you can pass `params[:time_zone]` straight to your model and it will convert the value into a string for storage.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `time_zone_select` is actually called `time_zone` rather than `timezone` so try doing `params['time_zone']`.

Comment: That is just a typo in the SO question. If he was using the wrong param key he would get `nil` and not a `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`.